# stickman animation in flex

Tags: apache-flex, animation

I am trying to build a stickman in Flex who will 
a) move across the screen with speed- based on slider value
b) do something different (jump/ sit down) when he reaches end of screen

I presume will need to switch between 3-4 images to simulate illusion of movement with parts of body moving. would this approach be right? Are there any similar examples I can learn from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how realistic you want it to look.

What you are saying could probably work, but if you wanted to get it looking/behaving really nicely I would recommend the book "[ActionScript Animation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590597915)." There were a couple of chapters in the book about kinetics that walked you through building a man that walked/jumped etc with sliders that could control not only his speed, but gravity, body segments size, etc.

I read the first edition that was on ActionScript 2 but there is a new one for ActionScript 3.

#### edit

You would want to check out *Chapter 13 Forward Kinematics: Making Things Walk*